# How to use variables in SQL Reporting 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to populate a combo box with a list of dates from a DB. Then based on user input I want to be change the Tablix to filter on only dates later than the selected date.

How can I do so?

Detailed steps will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need variables: you bind any filters to the relevant control in the [Parameter collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264.aspx)

For example, [Filtering, Grouping, and Sorting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627464.aspx) or [How to: Add a Filter to a Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255287.aspx)

For something [more obvious](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/reporting/report_parameters_p1.aspx) and [here too](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337460%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: do these apply for 2008 as well

Comment: @DotDot: yes. very little difference between 2005 and 2008